# How many integers can be made?

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

> The digits of a positive integer $n$ are four consecutive integers in decreasing order when read from left to right. How many integers $n$ can be made?

Since there is:

$$0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9$$

That is $10$ total options.

Possible combinations are:

$$\binom{10}{4} * 1$$

Since there is only one way to order them.

But that appears to be incorrect?

Comment: Did you use that the integers must be consecutive?

Comment: How should I go about this?

Comment: A good idea when faced with a problem like this is to start by writing down some examples of what it is you're trying to count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: How many ways can you choose the first (left most) digit?  Note everything else is fixed!

Comment: $9$ possible ways

Comment: @Lebes think again..  try with extremes, you may figure out the problem faster.

Comment: @Lebes: Before you answer the hint, ask yourself if you can choose the first (left most) digit to be $2$.

Comment: Perhaps it's slightly easier to start with the righmost digit.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I mixed it up. It can be: $a = 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3$ meaning, 7 choices.  One choice for next etc...

Comment: @Lebes That's good.